# How do I erase a map containing structures of maps which contain structures?

Tags: c++

I have the below code for creating a map which contains a structure which contains a map of structures.  My question is how to delete an element out of providerMap without leaving any memory leaks.  Can I just do a providerMap[prov_id].erase() or do I need to do a delete on the second or something more complex?

```
struct uriPrivs {
    std::string name;
    uchar properties;
};
struct providerValues {
    int KeepAlive;
    std::map<std::string /*uri*/, uriPrivs> uris;
};
std::map<std::string /*prov_id*/, providerValues> providerMap;

RISStorageManager::risStorageResponse RISStorageManager::update_provider(const std::string &prov_id, int KeepAlive) {

    if (providerMap.find(prov_id) == providerMap.end()) {
        providerValues x;
        x.KeepAlive = KeepAlive;
        providerMap[prov_id] = x;
        return risStorageCreated;
    } else {
        providerMap[prov_id].KeepAlive = KeepAlive;
        return risStorageUpdated;
    }
}
RISStorageManager::risStorageResponse RISStorageManager::update_uri(const std::string &prov_id, std::map<std::string, uriPrivs> &uris) {
    providerMap[prov_id].uris = uris;
}
```

Comment: If you don't have any calls to allocation functions, then you don't need any to deallocation functions.

Comment: You are doing it right. Lovely.

Comment: Normally, you'd iterate through the map objects, freeing them, if the objects contain allocated objects, then you add a deletion function to the object which clears the map/object which was allocated with it. This is why encapsulation is so useful.

Comment: @Sinn There are no pointers here. That's what's so nice about it.

Comment: It's funny, when beginners do things the right way, sometimes they can't quite believe it's that simple. But it is!

Comment: Then why, is he asking about contained objects memory deallocation? Stack variables/objects do not need to be explicitly deallocated.

Answer (score 4):

As already said, you do not need to explicitly deallocate any memory here. You are not "new"ing up anything yourself. Everything will be taken care of by the destructors of the map objects.

You could condense the update_provider function a little...

```
RISStorageManager::risStorageResponse update_provider(const std::string &prov_id, int KeepAlive)
{
   RISStorageManager::risStorageResponse response = (providerMap.end() == providerMap.find(prov_id)) ?
      risStorageCreated : risStorageUpdated;

   providerMap[prov_id].KeepAlive = KeepAlive;

   return response;
}
```

And here is some test code to explain a couple things...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
   // Create new provider and print result...
   std::cout << update_provider("test1", 1) << std::endl;

   // Add a URI to the first provider for fun...
   providerMap["test1"].uris["www.google.com"].name = "GOOGLE";
   providerMap["test1"].uris["www.google.com"].properties = 0xFF;

   // Create new provider and print result...
   std::cout << update_provider("test2", 1) << std::endl;

   // Create new provider and print result...
   std::cout << update_provider("test3", 1) << std::endl;

   // Update first provider and print result...
   std::cout << update_provider("test1", 0) << std::endl;

   // Explicitly remove first provider if you want...
   providerMap.erase("test1");

   //
   // Now only 2 providers are in map (test2 and test3).
   // The program will exit and the STL map destructors will take care of any
   // memory deallocation that is needed to clean up the maps. You don't need
   // to explicitly clean up anything unless you want to remove providers from
   // your map explicitly.
   //

   return 0;
}
```